# Lenovo Battery threshold on Z570 still not working; even with tlp

Tags: battery

I tried following the `tlp` stuff in [this manual](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html), but still when I watch the battery status, it still gets charged even after the *Stop Threshold* is set at 60% and the battery is at 99%

Does it even work for IdeaPads?

Answer (score 3):

after some attempts to set up the charging thresholds on ubuntu for my ideapad u330 I can tell you that it won't work for ideapads. tlp needs additional kernel modules to do this, either "tp-smapi-dkms" or "acpi-call-tools" (http://thinkwiki.de/TLP_-_Linux_Stromsparen#Ubuntu_12.04_bis_13.10 [link is in german]), both of which only work for certain thinkpads, not ideapads.

what eventually did the trick for me though was using the preinstalled win8 on my laptop (which I still have as a dual-boot backup) and set the thresholds there using the "Lenovo Energy Manager" software. Those changes affect the battery on a sub-OS level, so they also work on Ubuntu. It is a shame that we have to rely on Windows here, but that's what it is when Hardware companies have crappy Linux support.